# What is the number of binary sequences of length N in which every occurrence of zeros has even length?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

In my understanding, I need to generate some kind of regular expression, which can describe all the possible sequences, such as:

```
00
1
0000
0000111100
...
```

But I can't understand how it should look like.

Comment: Do you want the length or a regular expression? Because using the pumping lemma you can pick a subsequence with an odd number of $0$s, say $x$ and then duplicate it getting a word with $xx$ in it. You know that the remaining part of the word without $x$ also has an odd number of $0$s and thus the final word has an odd number of $0$s.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call $a_n$ the number of such sequences of length $n$.

Consider a generic sequence with the given property, it can either start with a $1$ or with two $0$.

In the first case there are $a_{n-1}$ sequences (why?) and in the second one $a_{n-2}$ (why?). So $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ for any $n \geq 3$.

But $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 2$. Then $a_n = F_{n+1}$ where $F_{n}$ is the $n$th [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Comment: Please explain your initial conditions.  If every occurrence of zeros has even length, why isn't $a_1 = 1$ (the sequence $1$) and $a_2 = 2$ (the sequences $11$ and $00$)?

Comment: Of course you're right! I'm editing

Comment: In the Fibonacci sequence, $F_1 = 1$, $F_2 = 1$, $F_3 = 2$, so $a_n = F_{n + 1}$.

Comment: Usually I use $F_0 =1, F_1=1,F_2=2$. It depends on the definitions. But internet says your definition is more used, so I'm going to edit it too

Comment: According to [www.oeis.org](http://oeis.org/search?q=Fibonacci&language=english&go=Search), $F_0 = 0$, $F_1 = 1$, and $F_n = F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2}$, where $n \geq 2$.  According to the link you provided, you should have $a_n = F_{n + 1}$.